# How to repeat downloadLink inside repeatingView Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I'm working on wicketpage where I want to display a dynamic table contains two columns. 
The first column should have a DownloadLink. The second column holds a simple label.
The problem is wicket displaying an empty first column so I can't see the downloadlink. 
How can I add a label to the downloadLink in this case ?

```
    ListDataProvider<String> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>(filesPaths);
    DataView<String> dataView = new DataView<String>("rows", listDataProvider) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item<String> item) {
            String filePath = item.getModelObject();
            RepeatingView repeatingView = new RepeatingView("dataRow");

            String idLink = repeatingView.newChildId();
            DownloadLink link = new DownloadLink(idLink, new File(filePath));
            link.add(new Label(idLink + "label", filePath));
            repeatingView.add(link);

            Label label = new Label(repeatingView.newChildId(), "(TEST)");
            label.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "color:  blue;"));
            repeatingView.add(label);

            item.add(repeatingView);
        }
    }; 
    add(dataView);
```

This is a section of the html page.

```
  <table>
    <tr wicket:id="rows">
      <td wicket:id="dataRow"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Links name like the following:

```
downloadLink.setBody(Model.of("Download"));
```

This will set the link to `<a href="yourHref">Download</a>`